# How to make sure every number of a bigger range is within some smaller ranges?

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have 3 smaller ranges like this:

```
var a = [ 1 , 5 ],
var b = [ 3 , 9 ],
var c = [ 8 , 20]
```

also we have a bigger range like this.

```
var d = [1 , 20]
```

the first number is the lower bound and the second number is the higher bound of the range.

How do I make sure that every number of range `d` is at least in of the smaller ranges (`a` or `b` or `c`) ?

the ranges can overlap each other.
for the above example the answer is `true`.

but if the ranges was this:

```
var a = [ 1 , 6 ], var b = [ 3 , 8 ], var c = [ 10 , 20]
```

The answer would be `false` because number number 9 is not in either of the a, b or c.

the number of ranges can be any number, this is just an example.

I've tried to combine the smaller ranges and delete the overlap between them but it's too complicated because of overlapping between them.

I could also check every number in d to see if it's in smaller ranges but d may be [1 , 1000000]. at this point it's not memory friendly.

Comment: are there only 2 numbers?

Comment: Yes the first number is the lower bound and the second number is the higher bound of the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for loop that just shifts target range's minimum forward based on list of ranges.
Uses 3 assertions for target range covered by a sorted list of ranges.  Note: assertions can probably be simplified/optimized so less than 3 comparisons have to be made.

sort the ranges first,
Given: each [x,y]=ranges[n], and [min,max]=d_range

- min < x, min is not covered by any range, = false
- max < x: no more ranges overlap, finished, = min > max
- min > max: all target range covered (min has passed maximum) = true

```js
fn = (abc, [min, max]) => {
  abc.sort((x, y) => x[0] - y[0])
  for (const [x, y] of abc) {
    if (min < x || max < x || min > max) break
    min = Math.max(min, y + 1)
  }
  return min > max
}

var a = [1, 6];
var b = [3, 8];
var c = [10, 20]
var d = [1, 20]
console.log(
  fn([a, b, c], d)
)

var a = [1, 6];
var b = [3, 9];
var c = [10, 20]
var d = [1, 20]
console.log(
  fn([a, b, c], d)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, That's a good approach and it's working. so you are checking if one of (upperbound + 1) of a range is not in the other ranges then the answer would be false? if this is the case why we need sorting?

Comment: The assertion min < x relies on x being in sorted order (knowing min is not inside any [x,y] range).  So it can return early.  If you'd like detailed explanation I can explain the reasoning for choosing this approach vs merging the [x,y] ranges.  The short of it is: O(N log N) for both approaches and similar algs/assertions, but this is simpler and defers efficiency to the sorting algorithm which can be adapted.  (And often presorted is the given problem).  So if I had actual performance problems I'd measure it on real data, because performance characteristics are highly dependent on it.

Comment: But yes you are correct, keeping a true/false flag or using lower and upper bound values instead of breaking out early on the assumption it is sorted would also work.

Comment: yes I check it on my real data and its O(N log N). It's good for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
Make a boolean array of size of the bigger range, `d` here

`var range = []`

Then for every small range, 
eg. a = [1 ,6], make range[1..6] true => meaning there exists a range to cover the index element.

In the end, if there are no `false` entries in the range array, you're covered. This can be done as below:

```
for(var i=0; i<range.length; i++) {
  if(!range[i]) return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: Yes it's good but the numbers are not always 20. d can also be something like this: [30, 400000000]. at this point it's a not memory friendly code

Answer (score 0):

the one question you have to decide is if you have ranges [1,4] & [6,10], then is [1,10] considered in range or not in range?

if it's in range, than the easiest solution is to find the absolute min and max of each of your smaller ranges and then see if d range fits those.

if its not considered "in-range", then maybe step through your smaller ranges and create a number hash and set it true for each number in the range:

```
var a = [ 1 , 5 ]
var numberHash = {}
for(let x= a[0]; x <= a[1] x++)
  numberHash[x] = true;

//repeat for each array

var d = [ 1 , 20 ]
var rangeIsGood = true;
for(let x= d[0]; x <= d[1] x++)
  if(!numberHash[x])
    rangeIsGood = false;

console.log(rangeIsGood);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine overlapping parts, get the count of the parts and return the check with length (1) and the wanted lower and upper bounds.

```js
const
    check = ([...values], range) => {
        let temp = values
            .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0] || b[1] - a[1])
            .reduce((r, [...a]) => {
                let last = r[r.length - 1];
                if (!last || last[1] < a[0]) r.push(a);
                else if (last[1] < a[1]) last[1] = a[1];
                return r;
            }, []);
        return temp.length === 1 && temp[0][0] === range[0] && temp[0][1] === range[1];
    };

console.log(check([[1, 5], [3, 9], [8, 20]], [1, 20])); // true
console.log(check([[1, 6], [3, 8], [10, 20]], [1, 20])); // false
```