# Get non-selected date ranges from the selected date ranges in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I have an array of date ranges(`selectedRanges`) which shows assigned dates for a member between the main date range. I want to know the date ranges where he/she is unassigned. Please refer to the below example.

```
mainDateRange = ['01-01-2020', '14-06-2020'];

selectedRanges = [
 ['03-01-2020','04-01-2020'],
 ['03-01-2020','05-01-2020'],  //overlapping dates
 ['11-01-2020','13-01-2020'],
 ['01-02-2020','20-02-2020'],
 ['15-03-2020','18-03-2020'],
 ['06-01-2020','06-01-2020'],  //date ranges will not be ordered
 ['03-01-2020','04-01-2020']
]; //dates that the member has work assigned
```

**Desired output**

```
excludedRanges = [
 ['01-01-2020','02-01-2020'],
 ['07-01-2020','10-01-2020'],
 ['14-01-2020','31-01-2020'],
 ['21-02-2020','14-03-2020'],
 ['19-03-2020','14-06-2020']
];  //shows all the unassigned periods(ranges)
```

`selectedRanges` date ranges will have ranges in random order and also may have duplicate and overlapping dates.

I have searched a lot and found nothing. I am only able to get the unselected dates, not as a range. Please help.

Thank you

Comment: In `mainDateRange`, the second date is before the first date, what does that mean? And can you further explain exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: By the way, the output you are expecting has one typo, it should be `'21-02-2020'` instead of `'21-01-2020'`. You can see the actual output in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used a similar approach to this: [How to make sure every number of a bigger range is within some smaller ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62287238/how-to-make-sure-every-number-of-a-bigger-range-is-within-some-smaller-ranges/62291438#62291438)

Convert all strings to Dates.  Sorts by minimum of range.
Moves minimum position forward, until it finds a gap, and pushes to res array.
Pushes range from last minimum to maximum if it exists

```js
mainDateRange = ['01-01-2020', '14-06-2020'];

selectedRanges = [
  ['03-01-2020', '04-01-2020'],
  ['03-01-2020', '05-01-2020'], //overlapping dates
  ['11-01-2020', '13-01-2020'],
  ['01-02-2020', '20-02-2020'],
  ['15-03-2020', '18-03-2020'],
  ['06-01-2020', '06-01-2020'], //date ranges will not be ordered
  ['03-01-2020', '04-01-2020']
]; //dates that the member has work assigned

function gapFinder(mainDateRange, selectedRanges) {
  const dateToInt = a => new Date(a.split('-').reverse().join('-'))
  const intToDate = a => new Date(a).toISOString().slice(0, 10).split('-').reverse().join('-')

  // convert to numbers
  selectedRanges = selectedRanges.map(r => r.map(dateToInt))
  // presort ranges
  selectedRanges.sort(([a, ], [b, ]) => a - b)

  let [min, max] = mainDateRange.map(dateToInt)
  const res = []
  for (const [x, y] of selectedRanges) {
    if (min > max) break
    if (min < x)
      res.push([min, x.setDate(x.getDate() - 1)])
    min = Math.max(min, y.setDate(y.getDate() + 1))
  }
  if (min <= max) res.push([min, max])

  return res.map(r => r.map(intToDate))
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(gapFinder(mainDateRange,selectedRanges)))

selectedRanges.push(['11-06-2020', '13-06-2020'])
console.log(JSON.stringify(gapFinder(mainDateRange,selectedRanges)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem, I'll propose an approach to achieve this desired behavior by doing the following:

- Transform all string dates into date objects.
- Sort the `selectedRanges` array in ascending order using the start and end dates. This sorting step is cricual to finding the date range gaps.
- Adding a "moving cursor" date that moves between the `mainDateRange` to find and add the missing ranges to the output array.

Before we start the date calculations, we'll need a few helper functions. I've added two functions to go back and forth between the date object and the string format you have (*dd-mm-yyyy*). Please note that you may not need these two helper function if you use something like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), but I won't impose an extra dependency on your project.

```
function stringToDate(stringDate) {
    const parts = stringDate.split('-').map((p) => parseInt(p));
    parts[1] -= 1;
    return new Date(...parts.reverse());
}
function dateToString(date) {
    return `${('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2)}-${('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)}-${date.getFullYear()}`;
}
```

I've also added a sorter function that makes sure the ranges are sorted in an ascending fashion (smaller ranges first).

```
function dateRangeSorter(a, b) {
    if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1;
    else if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1;
    if (a[1] < b[1]) return -1;
    else if (a[1] > b[1]) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Now we're good to go on the calculation, here is a code snippet that will log the output at the end.

```js
// data
const output = [];
const oneDayInMs = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const mainDateRange = ['01-01-2020', '14-06-2020'];
const selectedRanges = [
    ['03-01-2020','04-01-2020'],
    ['03-01-2020','05-01-2020'],
    ['11-01-2020','13-01-2020'],
    ['01-02-2020','20-02-2020'],
    ['15-03-2020','18-03-2020'],
    ['06-01-2020','06-01-2020'],
    ['03-01-2020','04-01-2020']
];

// helpers
function stringToDate(stringDate) {
    const parts = stringDate.split('-').map((p) => parseInt(p));
    parts[1] -= 1;
    return new Date(...parts.reverse());
}
function dateToString(date) {
    return `${('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2)}-${('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)}-${date.getFullYear()}`;
}
function dateRangeSorter(a, b) {
    if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1;
    else if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1;
    if (a[1] < b[1]) return -1;
    else if (a[1] > b[1]) return 1;
    return 0;
}

// transform into date and sort
const mainDateRangeAsDates = mainDateRange.map(stringToDate);
const selectedRangesAsDates = selectedRanges.map((range) => (range.map(stringToDate)))
                                            .sort(dateRangeSorter);
// start at the beginning of the main date range
let movingDate = mainDateRangeAsDates[0];
// loop through the selected ranges
selectedRangesAsDates.forEach(([startDate, endDate]) => {
    // if there's a gap, add it to the output
    if (movingDate < startDate) {
        output.push([
            dateToString(movingDate),
            dateToString(new Date(startDate.getTime() - oneDayInMs))
        ]);
    }
    // move the cursor date to one day after the end of current rage
    movingDate = new Date(endDate.getTime() + oneDayInMs);
});
// if there is a gap at the end, add it as well
if (movingDate < mainDateRangeAsDates[1]) {
    output.push([
        dateToString(movingDate),
        dateToString(mainDateRangeAsDates[1])
    ]);
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Genius! I guess this is it. I will apply this solution and let you know. Please give me some time. I hope you have fun. 